# Django server in one computer, client in other computer

Tags: django, dajax

1. I downloaded the latest `django-dajaxice` zip file from github then
   unzip it.
2. Then I enter `django-dajaxice-master/examples` folder, run 'python
   manage.py runserver 13.122.241.172:80', (which is my computer's ip).

The server started normally. In this server computer, I can visit http13.122.241.172/ and the page displays normally. Then I click the 'Hello' button, I can get the right response.

*Problem:*

In my collegue's computer, whose ip is 13.122.242.16, he can visit `http13.122.241.172/` , BUT, when he click the 'Hello' button, there is NO response!

*Debugging:*

Then I check the command window, I see when he click the button, my server never receive the "`GET /dajaxice/simple.hello/?argv=undefined HTTP/1.1`" request! I am so confused by this problem and have been working on it for three days. Anyone could help me?

*Note:*

- Django Version is `1.4.20`.
- Django Settings: DEBUG=True.

My colleague can visit http://www.dajaxproject.com/dajaxice/ and if he click 'Get message from server!' he can get the server response.

***Code:***

This is the relevant code from the [dajaxice project](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajaxice/tree/master/examples/simple):

**index.html (template)**

```
{% load dajaxice_templatetags %}
<html>
<head>
{% dajaxice_js_import 'nocsrf' %}
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="Dajaxice.simple.hello(function(d){alert(d.message);})">Hello</button>
    <button onclick="Dajaxice.simple.bye(function(d){alert(d.message);})">Bye</button>
    <button onclick="Dajaxice.more.complex.bye(function(d){alert(d.message);})">Complex Bye</button>
    <button onclick="Dajaxice.simple.lol(function(d){alert(d.message);})">LOL</button>
    <button onclick="Dajaxice.simple.get_args(function(d){alert(d.message);}, {'foo': 'var'})">GET args</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**ajax.py**

```
import json

from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register


@dajaxice_register(method='GET')
@dajaxice_register(method='POST', name='other_post')
def hello(request):
    return json.dumps({'message': 'hello'})


@dajaxice_register(method='GET')
@dajaxice_register(method='POST', name="more.complex.bye")
def bye(request):
    raise Exception("PUMMMM")
    return json.dumps({'message': 'bye'})


@dajaxice_register
def lol(request):
    return json.dumps({'message': 'lol'})


@dajaxice_register(method='GET')
def get_args(request, foo):
    return json.dumps({'message': 'hello get args %s' % foo})
```

***Progress:***

- Thanks for your help to this topic. I'm newbie here. Stackoverflow really a great place.
- Now I have found the problem's crux: In my server computer I use IE11, BUT in my colleague's computer, he uses IE9. If he changes to Chrome, it will be OK. But it still confuses me how should I do with other people who only have IE9.

Comment: You should post your code as it probably contains some error.

Comment: @geckon the code is not mine. I just download the [project](https://codeload.github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajaxice/zip/master) and run the example. Maybe I can post it here but I think people who use dajax already has the source so as well as the example. But maybe the never try run the server on his own computer but access it in another computer with IE9.

Comment: Thanks. Specifying the browser can be important too. Also thanks for improving the formatting of your question.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question and add the relevant code. Maybe someone else will see something in it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would try to do is to make sure that the IE9 has the [Compatibility View](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2536204) turned off.

Also please note that the author of django-dajaxice himself [doesn't recommend using the package](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajaxice#should-i-use-django-dajaxice):

> In a word, No. I created this project 4 years ago as a cool tool in
>   order to solve one specific problem I had at that time.
>
> These days using this project is a bad idea.
>
> Perhaps I'm more pragmatic now, perhaps my vision of how my django
>   projects should be coupled to libraries like this has change, or
>   perhaps these days I really treasure the purity and simplicity of a
>   vanilla django development.
>
> If you want to mimic what this project does, you would only need some
>   simple views and jQuery.
>
> Forget about adding more unnecessary complexity. Keep things simple.

Therefore I would consider if you really need dajaxice or I can do it other way.